# compiler warning with reflection calling empty arg constructor

Tags: java

This works great:

```
this.getClass().getConstructor(null).newInstance(null);
```

But I want to get rid of this warning:

"The argument of type null should explicitly be cast to Class[] for the invocation of the varargs method getConstructor(Class...) from type Class. It could alternatively be cast to Class for a varargs invocation"

Comment: you can usually leave parameters blank instead of filling in a null, e.g. `newInstance()`. `getConstructor((Class[]) null)` does not work while `getConstructor(null)` gives you that warning?

Comment: What is the context you're using the code fragment in? You do know you can simply call `this.getClass().newInstance()`, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You say:

> This works great:
>
> ```
> this.getClass().getConstructor(null).newInstance(null);
> ```

In fact it doesn't "work great".  It compiles (with warnings that are important) and then the compiled code gives a runtime exception.

Your code is actually equivalent to this:

```
  this.getClass().getConstructor((Class[]) null).newInstance(null);
```

and it is the `getConstructor((Class[]) null)` call that is causing the problem.  That call is saying "give me a constructor ... but I'm not saying what the argument types are".  That doesn't work.  The `getConstructor(Class ...)` method does not do wildcard / fuzzy matching.  (The alternative suggested by the compiler ... `getConstructor((Class) null)` ... won't work either.)

---

So what is the fix?

- If you are trying to select the "no-args" constructor then you should write it like this:

  ```
   getConstructor()
  ```

  or

  ```
   getConstructor(new Class[0])   // equivalent
  ```

  or replace the complete statement with this:

  ```
   this.getClass().newInstance()
  ```
- If you are trying to select "any constructor with one argument", or something like that, then you will need to use `getConstructors()`.  Then you need to iterate over the result array to select the constructor that you want.
- If you trying to do something else, you will need to explain.

Comment: Thank you, `this.getClass().getConstructor().newInstance()` works with no compiler warnings.